# Can I make the launcher Icons smaller than 32 pixels?

Tags: unity, launcher

Why can't the "Launcher" Icons be made smaller? At the smallest setting, they are still 4 times bigger than they need to be on a 10" Netbook. The Icons in the "Top Panel" are much smaller and we users don't have a problem selecting them.

Answer (score 10):

## 12.04 and later

Am guessing that when you say "smallest setting" you mean the Unity plugin in the CCSM (CompizConfig System Manager). For the moment the 32 value in the Experimental Tab for the "Launcher Icon Size" is the smallest that is available. I also believe a smaller value should be available. 28, 24, 20, 18 to a minimum like 8x8 (For people like me with insect precise eyes).

There is an option with `gconf-editor` in the **schemas/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/icon_size** address. But the value is  and currently is not editable. It will soon be however.

**UPDATE** - Starting with 13.04, users will be able to resize the icons from 8 to 64 through the CCSM.

First install the CCSM (Compiz Config Settings Manager) if you have not yet done so:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
```

In Dash, type **cc** which should show the Compiz Config Settings Manager app. Open it and go to the Unity plugin:

[image]

Select the **Launcher** tab:

[image]

Change the value in the **Launcher Icon Size** option:

[image]

You can change it from 8 to 64. The only deal is, if you right click the Desktop and select **Change Desktop Background**, the value for the icons found there will be the one applied. Right now, both, the CCSM Icon size and the Desktop Icon size or not using the same variable for this.

As suggested by [Ben Lutgens](https://askubuntu.com/users/17322/ben-lutgens) in the comments you can easily accomplish the same by typing the following in the termina:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size "24"
```

where the 24 will be the icon size. You can change this value from 8 to 64 depending on your TV, Monitor or Display. In my case 20 is perfect.

Comment: Any idea when this will be editable? Is there any way to speed this along?

Comment: Sorry no ATM yet. There is another issue I am checking that affects mostly TVs with 16:9 and 16:10 where the launcher icons tends to look bigger than they should. This is related to the icons being a X:X size instead of also being a X:Y size. For example 32x32, 32x24, 24x32...

Comment: I Installed today 13.04 and changed the icon size via the dconf tool(installed by default).
org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell
key: icon-size, value:16

Comment: I used this command:dconf  write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/icon-size "24"

Comment: @BenLutgens I find your command better than my GUI approach. Maybe you can post it as an answer.

Comment: I didn't see a way to post it that way.

Answer (score 4):

### 12.04

Other than modifying the source code itself, the current size limit for icons on the launcher is 32 pixels, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

### 12.04

See  [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/713087)  why launcher icon less than 32 pixels is not currently allowed. Be sure to read  [14th](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/713087/comments/14)  Comment.

Though this is frustrating for people with smaller screen, currently it seems there is no solution available.

Answer (score 3):

## 14.04

From 14.04 the launcher icon size can be reduced below 32 pixels in size - all the way down to 16 pixels.

Pictures paint a thousand words:

Standard size:

[image]

Smallest size:

[image]

#### how to

[image: pic]

[image: pic]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried CONFINITY
http://sourceforge.net/projects/confity/files/confity_1.0/confity_1.0.deb/download

I have not tested it but it may work for unity 2D

Atul Kakrana