# Hide the Unity Launcher, when an application is maximized

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher

I would like to hide the launcher only when an application goes maximized. This would be really useful when using my browser, because I could have that additional space.
Auto-hiding the Launcher isn't good for me, since I want to use the launcher, just not when an application is maximized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First workaround**

I wrote a little script for you. You can download it [here](https://github.com/c0rp-aubakirov/unity-launcher-toggle). There is also description how to install and use script. If you have any doubts please let me know

---

**One more workaround**

Create bash script with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURR_WIN_NAME=`xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname`
wmctrl -r $CURR_WIN_NAME -b toggle,fullscreen
```

Save it somewhere, for example `/home/sebastian/bash_scripts/fullscreen`. Make it executable

```
$ chmod +x /home/sebastian/bash_scripts/fullscreen
```

Go to `System Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Custom Shortcuts`.

Add new shortcut, where:

`Name:` **fullscreen**

`Command:` **/home/sebastian/bash_scripts/fullscreen**

[image]

Now add some Shortcut for this script, for example <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Now try press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> while using any application

---

For more information:

[Detecting Currently Active Window](https://superuser.com/questions/382616/detecting-currently-active-window)

[Launch Application In Full Screen Mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374877/trying-to-launch-application-in-full-screen-mode-on-boot)

Comment: I don't think you get what I mean. I want to hide the launcher, not make an application fullscreen. Kindof like the intelligent mode in Ubuntu 11 but only hide when the active window is maximized.

Comment: @Sebastian I wrote script and update answer

Comment: I guess the best way to explain it is like: If an application is FOCUSED, and is in the MAXIMIZED state, then hide the Unity launcher ONLY, I need the top panel. If the application that's maximized gets unfocused or unmaximized, show the launcher(the launcher on the side).

Comment: @Sebastian That is exactly what I did [here](https://github.com/c0rp-aubakirov/unity-launcher-toggle). This link also in answer

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see that. It seems like that the script really does work, gonna try it out, and if it works, I'm going to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @Sebastian I wrote this script before your last comment. So it ignores if window Maximized or not. If you still need it, let me know

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

If you want more spaces than maximize just press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: What if I'm doing other stuff in other windows, and I want to look at the time..? I don't want to press F11 each time I go back to Firefox.

Comment: @Sebastian What you want exactly? do you want to see the time? or do you want to hide the launcher? or do you want to additional spaces? You want to see the time, access the launcher, more space at the same time???

Comment: @Sebastian You can always make unity launcher icons with small size. see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18345/how-to-resize-the-unity-launcher) and with smaller size see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70306/can-i-make-the-launcher-icons-smaller-than-32-pixels). thanks