# Show the Unity Launcher, when desktop is opened

Tags: unity, launcher

Firstly, sorry but maybe, my English isn't enough.

I'm using "auto hide" function for Unity launcher. But I want to show the launcher when desktop is appearing. (so, show the launcher only when I using desktop or there is no maximized window)

How can I do this without a bash script? (execute it with shortcut etc. I don't want this)

Comment: I have a question. Maybe this question will help someone smarter than I am. You want to inspect your window manager to see if an application window is opened. If no application is present, then automatically display the launcher? If an application window is detected but not maximized, also show the launcher? If window is detected and maximized, do nothing? Three conditions. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi D75. I want to see my launcher like Plank or Docky. They're appearing when no maximized window or we're in our desktop. I want to see my launcher like them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you weren't looking for a script or a shortcut, but you have to press or click on something to maximize the window.

There is another post asking the same thing that was resolved with a script and a key-binding. The thing is, the work is already done. You just need to copy the script and set the input key. What is the reason this won't work for you?

[Previous solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519589/hide-the-unity-launcher-when-an-application-is-maximized)

Comment: I know this solution. I said that "I dont want to use a shortcut for a script" for this. Because this isn't a good solution. If I want, I would use this solution.  But thanks :)

Comment: I mentioned that. I asked you why you didn't want to use it. You might have had a circumstantial need (like touch screen device) and if someone else knew about it, they could consider that in the solution.

Comment: My English is poor, so I don't explain my sentences :( .. I dont want because it should be easy. Everytime  use a shortcut when I'm using desktop isn't a solution. There is an option like this already (When launcher's auto hide mode is open, it appears when mouse on over it already. ) But I want an automatic option. It should appear when I'm seeing desktop  (Like Plank or Docky) or when there is no maximized window.   I'm waiting for every solution except shortcut > bash script.   :)

Comment: Ah sorry! I've tried this solution completely now. It has a great option like "remember the app" for hide launcher. I wasn't know that before. I will choose your answer as my question's answer.

Comment: I've been a while a while. It looks like you have something that works. I'm glad you have resolved the problem.